# Marshall Java object to an xml String using JAX-RPC

Tags: java, marshalling, jax-rpc

I need to marshall a java object using jax-RPC?
Marshalling using JAXB is pretty simple

```
  JAXBContext.newInstance("myClassName").createMarshaller.marshall(myObject,new ByteArrayOutputStream Object);
```

but no similar way found for JAX-RPC. Anyone did this before?

Any Help is highly appreciated!